# How to combine the functionality of a list with a textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, cakephp

Right now I have a form that I created in cakephp and it works fine but the problem I am running into is that we run queries off of the type in the database and there have been some user errors with spelling so I would like to have a list with the most common types that you can select from but if it is not in the list you can still type in something different.

I found this jquery autocomplete combobox that works great but I am not able to enter something that is not in the list. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

I don't know if you need to see my form or not but I will post it anyway

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->create( 'Credential', array( 'class' => 'popup_form' ) );
echo $this->Form->hidden( 'account_id', array( 'value' => $account_id ) );
echo $this->Form->hidden( 'user_id', array( 'value' => $currentUser['User']['id'] ) );
echo $this->Form->hidden( 'created', array( 'value' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ) );
echo $this->Form->hidden( 'modified', array( 'value' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ) );
echo '<br/><br/>';
echo $this->Form->input( 'type', array( 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Account Type' ) );
echo '<br/><br/>';
echo $this->Form->input( 'url', array( 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'URL' ) );
echo '<br/><br/>';
echo $this->Form->input( 'username', array( 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Username' ) );
echo '<br/><br/>';
echo $this->Form->input( 'password', array( 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Password' ) );
echo '<br/><br/>';
echo $this->Js->submit( 'Create Credential', array( 'div' => false, 'class' => 'button white medium', 'before' => 'return submitForm();', 'success' => "$('#qtip-add_account_credential').hide();", 'complete' => 'loadTasks();' ) );
echo '<br/><br/>';
echo $this->Form->end();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(){
        var x = document.getElementById("CredentialType").value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("Account Type must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am a backend developer and would love any help I could get on the front end. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are searching for is a *datalist* (new in HTML5):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

It provides an form input with a predefined list of options, which appears as soon as the user's input matches one of the entries.

**BUT**: it seems not to be supported in Safari

In your case it would look like that:

```
<input name="type" list="AccountTypes" placeholder="Account Type">

<datalist id="AccountTypes">
   <option value="admin">
   <option value="user">
   <option value="something else">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks that was simpler than I thought it would be. I thought I was going to have to do it with javascript.